# How do I access the elements of the array returned to the client from a Cloud Function (kotlin/typescript)?

Tags: javascript, java, android, typescript, kotlin

My app calls a cloud function called getGroupsInfo. It returns 3 values: `result`, `message`, and `groupsInfo`.

In the Logcat, I printed out the 3 values and below is the result. I now need to use each element in the `groupsInfo` array, but I'm not sure how to access each one. In the example below, I tried to access the first element but it didn't work.

```
fs.getGroupsInfo()
            .continueWith { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) { 
                    Log.e(tag, "Result1: ${task.result?.get("result")}") //case sensitive
                    Log.e(tag, "Result2: ${task.result?.get("message")}") //case sensitive
                    Log.e(tag, "GroupsInfo: ${task.result?.get("groupsInfo")}") //case sensitive
                    val result = task.result?.get("result")
                    val message = task.result?.get("message")
                    if (result == 1) {    
                        var groupsInfo: Array<Any?> = arrayOf(task.result?.get("groupsInfo"))
                        Log.e(tag, groupsInfo[0].toString())

                    } else {
                        Log.e(tag, "Loading failed.")
                        Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Could not load groups.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e(tag, "Result3: ${task.result?.get("result")}") //case sensitive
                    Log.e(tag, "Result4: ${task.result?.get("message")}") //case sensitive
                    Toast.makeText(baseContext, "There was a system error while trying to load the groups.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }

2021-05-09 20:13:33.061 8512-8512/com.example.2 E/_ActivityGroups: Result1: 1
2021-05-09 20:13:33.061 8512-8512/com.example.2 E/_ActivityGroups: Result2: 
2021-05-09 20:13:33.061 8512-8512/com.example.2 E/_ActivityGroups: GroupsInfo: [73Xwaz7vAOM39e1KVPu8, NOti0G0Me0VSte48I2O0]
2021-05-09 20:13:33.061 8512-8512/com.example.2 E/_ActivityGroups: Loading groups was successful!
2021-05-09 20:13:33.062 8512-8512/com.example.2 E/_ActivityGroups: [73Xwaz7vAOM39e1KVPu8, NOti0G0Me0VSte48I2O0]
```

Answer (score 0):

In my approach the easy way to access the elements is
Iterating with for loop

```
task.result?.get("groupInfo").toList().map { /**incase it's not string*/ it.toString() } .forEach {
      Log.d(tag, "$it")
}
```